# Python One Server and Multiple Clients

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, camera, client, server

I am new to sockets. I am writing a program for a camera network. For now I am using two cameras to capture an image and obtain a red object's location. Each camera is connected to a client. I am using threading to get the data from both clients.

I am able to view the data obtained, but for reason I am not able to manipulate the data.

Here is my codes:

tc1.py

```
import socket
import cv2
import numpy as np
import PySal

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 8089))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    xt, yt = PySal.track_R(frame)
    if xt > 0 :    
        tt = "c1 = "str(xt) + ", " + str(yt)
        clientsocket.send(tt)
```

tc2.py

```
import socket
import cv2
import numpy as np
import PySal

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 8088))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    xt, yt = PySal.track_R(frame)
    if xt > 0 :    
        tt = "c2 = "str(xt) + ", " + str(yt)
        clientsocket.send(tt)
```

ts1.py

```
import socket
def ts1():
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8089))
    serversocket.listen(5) 
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    while True:    
        buf = connection.recv(64)
        if len(buf) > 0:
            print buf
```

ts2.py

```
import socket
def ts2():
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8088))
    serversocket.listen(5) 
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    while True:   
        buf1 = connection.recv(64)
        if len(buf1) > 0:
            print buf1
```

server.py

```
from ts1 import ts1
from ts2 import ts2
from threading import Thread

if __name__ == '__main__':


    Thread(target = ts1).start()
    Thread(target = ts2).start()
```

So basically I am threading both ts1.py and ts2.py to obtain inputs from the two clients.

Is there a way to do the same but with one server and two clients?

Answer (score 0):

Have a server controller by updating ts1 and removing ts2.

```
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8088))
serversocket.listen(5)
While True:
  connection, address = serversocket.accept()
  Thread reader_thread passing in connection - exit on end of read.
```

This produces short-lived threads that serve one connection, read the file then exit. Since we are not delayed by the read, the accept can connect to as many clients as you like.

A more complete example based on your code is:

```
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8088))
serversocket.listen(5)
While True:
  connection, address = serversocket.accept()
  def receiver():
    buf1 = connection.recv(4096)
    while True:
      if len(buf1) > 0:
          print buf1
  rt = Thread(target=receiver)
```

This method treats the thread as a closure with access to connection from the calling function. Alternatively the Thread creation has a 'args' option so you can pass the data in. For the OO approach you can create a class based on Thread.

I am assuming from your code that the camera reader threads are never meant to terminate. The code should be improved to reconnect if an exception is thrown or the socket drops. This would be on the client/camera side.

Note that threads are light-weight. They share memory. When you replace "print buf1" with something more, be careful not to update common objects with the semaphores and locks that litter thread interacting code.

Comment: I have tired this but its not working. I am new to threading too, what does this mean?
Thread reader_thread passing in connection - exit on end of read.

Comment: sorry, I was short on time so reverted to English. It would be something like: - ok I guess it will have to be a edited in the answer...

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will give it a try and update this post.